# ATSPACE.COM has broken HELO / EHLO command for SMTP transaction?

Tags: email, smtp, telnet

SMTP connection from my laptop to my ISP has worked fine for years when my computer sends "EHLO [10.0.0.107]" to introduce itself.  It happens to be a Mac OSX using Mail, but that's irrelevant because I'm typing the tests manually using telnet command line, tested from a Mac, a Win10, even a Pi, and also from elsewhere in the nation.

Recently my for-pay ATSPACE.COM SMTP server has begun failing with a "#103b" error as soon as I complete the "rcpt to:" command in the SMTP conversation. I've traced this back to the EHLO command because any other fully qualified domain name submitted with the EHLO command works without a #103b error -- even domain names that have nothing to do with me.

I've also tried SMTP conversation with another ISP SMTP server (1and1.com)  using the identical commands and everything works fine.

Two questions:

1) If you have an ATSPACE.COM account, can you test your SMTP capability manually with telnet and post a log of your command line conversation?  Please mask out your username and password before posting it.

2) I think submitting my local IP with the EHLO command is okay (it worked for years with atspace and still works with 1and1) and I know submitting any other URL works fine.  Can you point me toward a reference that says submitting a local IP address is within specs? I need to press this point with atspace tech support which has run me around the pole for about a month now.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321):

2.3.5.  Domain Names

> (...) The domain name given in the EHLO command MUST be either a
> primary host name (a domain name that resolves to an address RR) or,
> if the host has no name, an address literal (...)

4.1.3.  Address Literals

> Sometimes a host is not known to the domain name system and
> communication (and, in particular, communication to report and repair
> the error) is blocked.  To bypass this barrier, a special literal form
> of the address is allowed as an alternative to a domain name. For IPv4
> addresses, this form uses four small decimal integers separated by
> dots and enclosed by brackets such as [123.255.37.2], which indicates
> an (IPv4) Internet Address in sequence-of-octets form. (...)

But then in 7.9:

> It is a well-established principle that an SMTP server may refuse to
> accept mail for any operational or technical reason that makes sense
> to the site providing the server. (...)

Comment: Dusan,  I see the reference you sent.  Thank you!  It appears Mac OSX Mail is sending [10.0.0.107] per Para 4.1.3.  It seems that ATSPACE.COM is not complying with the standard and is refusing all my SMTP mail.  Arrghh...   I understand Para 7.9, although because they are a paid email service provider, it seems incorrect that they would refuse to comply with the standard.      If you are thinking about using them as your ISP, maybe think again.  :-(    I wonder if I can force Mac Mail to send something else.

Comment: Continued conversations with ATSPACE.COM are hitting a wall.  Is there a recommended place I can clearly blackball them with an explanation that they will not comply withe the RFC?  I want others to avoid the problem I have landed in, and perhaps others will complain and apply pressure for them to comply.

Comment: Honestly, if I were in your place, I would give up and either change mail client or email provider... Their server, their rules.